# htaccess - How to make the "www" in an URL optional?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to write a redirect that works if a page is accessed with only `http://` and also with `http://www.`.

This is what I've got:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$example.com$
```

This should work no matter how the URL begins, but I would like to be as specific as possible.

I already tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^(http:\/\/)$^(www\.)$example.com$
```

How do I have to write a rewrite condition that works for a pages with only `http://` and `http://www.`?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
```

Notes

- `(?:www\.)?` gives you an optional `www.` group
- `[NC]` makes the match case-insensitive